# Average Response times using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in a MySQL Database. one called `tickets` and the other is `ticket_updates`

tickets has the following columns:

1. sequence
2. ticketnumber
3. datetime

and ticket_updates

1. sequence
2. ticket_seq
3. datetime
4. starttime
5. endtime

the `ticket_seq` column in the `ticket_updates` table links with the `ticketnumber` column in the `tickets` table. There may be multiple rows in `ticket_updates` linking to one row in the `tickets` table.

I want to show an average response time for how long it takes for the tickets to be replied to. the `datetime` column in both tables is a full timestamp of when the row was added/inserted `(Y-m-d H:i:s)`

how can i show average response times for, say the last week?

Comment: Surely "the ticket_seq column in the ticket_updates table links with the *sequence* column in the tickets table. " !?!?!? Hm, maybe I'm coming to this late...

Comment: no it links with the ticketnumber column in  the tickets table, not the sequence column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your chat wit Andy Jones I understand that you define the response time of a ticket as the time elapsed between `tickets.datetime` and the first `ticket_updates.datetime` for that ticket. In that case, the following query returns the average response time in seconds for tickets added in the last 7 days.

```sql
SELECT avg(response_seconds)
  FROM (
     SELECT time_to_sec(timediff(min(u.datetime), t.datetime)) AS response_seconds
       FROM tickets t
       JOIN ticket_updates u
         ON t.ticketnumber = u.ticket_seq
      WHERE t.datetime > now() - INTERVAL 7 day
      GROUP BY t.ticketnumber ) AS r
```

Comment: the column in tickets is datetime and also in ticket_updates is datetime

Comment: perfect - thank you. does this select the row added first into the ticket_updates table?

Comment: It selects the row with the earliest `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

I've assembled a full example. I assumed some things about your data - if the columns have wrong types, change appropriately. I'm also going to return the average update time in seconds.

```
CREATE TABLE tickets (
  sequence int(10) not null auto_increment primary key,
  ticket_number int(10) not null default 0,
  date_added timestamp,
  index ticket_number_index (ticket_number)
  );

INSERT INTO tickets (ticket_number, date_added) VALUES
  (1, '2013-12-01 01:00:00'),
  (2, '2013-12-15 02:00:00'),
  (3, '2013-12-10 03:00:00'),
  (4, '2013-12-13 04:00:00'),
  (5, '2013-12-17 05:00:00');


CREATE TABLE ticket_updates (
  sequence int(10) not null auto_increment primary key,
  ticket_number int(10) not null default 0,
  date_added timestamp,
  starttime datetime,
  endtime datetime,
  index ticket_number_index (ticket_number)
  );

INSERT INTO ticket_updates (ticket_number, starttime, endtime, date_added) VALUES
  (1, '2013-12-01 01:01:00', '2013-12-01 01:02:00', '2013-12-01 01:02:00'),
  (1, '2013-12-01 01:01:00', '2013-12-01 01:02:00', '2013-12-01 01:02:00'),
  (2, '2013-12-15 02:01:00', '2013-12-15 02:02:00', '2013-12-15 02:02:00'),
  (2, '2013-12-15 02:01:00', '2013-12-15 02:02:00', '2013-12-15 02:02:00'),
  (2, '2013-12-15 02:01:00', '2013-12-15 02:02:00', '2013-12-15 02:02:00'),
  (2, '2013-12-15 02:02:00', '2013-12-15 02:02:50', '2013-12-15 02:02:50'),
  (4, '2013-12-13 04:01:00', '2013-12-13 04:02:00', '2013-12-13 04:02:00'),
  (4, '2013-12-13 04:01:00', '2013-12-13 04:05:30', '2013-12-13 04:05:30'),
  (5, '2013-12-17 05:01:00', '2013-12-17 05:03:00', '2013-12-17 05:03:00');
```

You can then run this query...

```
SELECT SUM(TO_SECONDS(ticket_updates.date_added) - TO_SECONDS(tickets.date_added)) / count(*) as update_time
FROM tickets, ticket_updates
WHERE tickets.ticket_number = ticket_updates.ticket_number AND
  ticket_updates.date_added > now() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Not sure if this is quite exactly what you're looking for - but this (and the fiddle) might help move you closer to the answer.

See Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c0acc/1

Comment: How do I calculate the average response times for all tickets in the past X days?

Comment: The `WHERE date_added > now() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK` only grabs update rows added within the last week - so this should calculate average response times for all tickets with the last X period. You could change to `now() - INTERVAL X DAY` if that works better.

Comment: I looked at your fiddle and it is showing multiple ticket numbers and update_time for each ticket. I want to show average response time of ALL tickets in the last day/week...

Comment: Oh - then simply remove the `GROUP BY ticket_number` row. That will calculate it for everything.

Comment: And it's not working out the average time between start time and end time, I need to work out average response time from datetime (tickets table) and starttime (ticket_updates)

Comment: I see - hang on I misunderstood the question

Comment: So tickets.datetime is a timestamp for when the row was inserted then ticket_updates.starttime is when the ticket was first responded to so I need to work out average time it takes for updates to be added to tickets

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43466/discussion-between-andy-jones-and-charliejsford)

Answer (score 0):

The average is sum of all values (in your case you have to convert datetime to UNIX timestamp) and then divide this sum to the total count. 
The conversion can be done via MySQL by issuing the command, for example

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(str_to_date('30/05/2011','%d/%m/%Y'));
```

or in PHP when displaying the results. It depends on the logic and structure of your project.

Comment: at the moment i have nothing, i wasnt sure where to start on it

Comment: I think this the right path, create your MySQL tables structures, then populate them with values, then implement PHP (or if you prefer ASP) scripts, which will connect to database and extract the data.

Comment: do you have a full example please?